# Expected value of least squares estimator $\hat{\beta}$

Tags: least-squares, expected-value, matrix

Given $\hat{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}(X^{T}Y)$, how do you derive the expected value? I found answers for finding the variance matrix but not the expected value.

Answer (score 6):

Note that in regression we condition on $X$.

Hence expressions like $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ will be a matrix of constants.

Recall that $Y=X\beta+e$, and just apply linearity of expectation, and that E[e]=0.

Edit:

$E[\hat{\beta}]=E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY]=E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta+e)]$

$\hspace{1cm}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX E[\beta]+(X^TX)^{-1}X^T E[e]=I\beta+\,0=\beta$

Comment: E[$\hat{\beta}$|X]=E[$\beta+(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$e|X]
=E[$\beta$]+$(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$E(e|X)
=E[$\beta$]
=$\beta$
is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that works. Since you seem to have it, I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Thank you. The matrix of constants comment helped greatly.

Comment: Why do you take the expectation of $\hat{\beta}$ by conditioning on $X$, @Kyle? It doesn't make sense to me since $X$ is the design matrix, and always constant by design.Thus it's NOT a random variable. The proof by direct expectation on $\hat{\beta}$ is obvious to me though.

Comment: @Aaron nothing is lost by explicitly mentioning the conditioning.

Comment: ... It's typically a part of the formulation of the regression model - regression is often formulated in terms of $E[Y|X=x]=X\beta$. (e.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Regression_models): "usually formalized as $E(Y | X) = f(X, β)$"), though sometimes - e.g. when assuming normality - in terms of the conditional distribution, such as $(Y|X=x)\sim N(X\beta,\sigma^2)$. There's no shortage of references doing one or the other; it's probably better to mention it in the derivation rather than omit it (as I did).

Comment: Here's a video that explains it, assuming a design matrix of full rank:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyBtfhQsf44